# UDF's on different sheets calling eachother return error 2015

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I have 2 sheets with 3 UDF's in the first and 2 in the second.

- sheet 1 is a monthly matrix with 1 column for each day where people put in their hours on the rows beneath. On 3 specific rows there are UDF's that consolidate the data in the column above, referencing the row as an argument. I do the function call like below to avoid having to make the UDF volatile (which prolongs calculation time greatly if I do), so the UDF's result updates when anything changes in column R:

  ```
  calculateOvertime(R:R)
  ```
- On sheet 2, the days of the month are in rows (not columns) where one can put in details about their day IF they did overtime. This is detected by one of the UDF's in sheet 1, so the 2 UDF's here require data calculated by a UDF in sheet 1

I have some strange issues with this setup:

- For some reason, when I switch tabs, all cells containing any of these functions show up as #VALUE!. I have to add "Application.CalculateFull" to an event handler that fires whenever the tab is activated:

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_activate()
      Application.CalculateFull
  End Sub
  ```
- The UDF's that reference a cell containing another UDF on the other tab, will always get '2015!' as a value, referring to error 2015 (a Value error, because the cell contains #VALUE! when the sheet is not active)

Obviously these 2 issues are connected because when I shift sheets, the UDF-calculated values in the non-active sheet are somehow lost.

My method of getting a value from a cell is as follows. I figure out on which row the label in column A is by using the Find() function

```
Dim compensationRowIndex As Integer
compensationRowIndex = CInt(othersheet.Range("A1:A250").Find("COMPENSATION").Row)
```

then I get the value and cast it to a Single

```
Dim compensation As Single
compensation = CSng(othersheet.Cells(compensationRowIndex , columnIndex).Value)
```

the variable 'compensation' holds the value 2015 always.

Is there any way around this? Also when I want to print the sheets, all cells containing UDF's are filled with #VALUE!. My guess is : If I can make issue 1 go away, so will issue 2.

ANY help on this is much appreciated. I've been troubleshooting this for almost a whole day now and haven't found a solution googling the symptoms.

Comment: `#######` means you don't have enough display space in the cell.  Try making the column size bigger to make that go away.

Comment: Are your *UDFs* **Volatile ??**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent is referring to http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/271165-udf-volatile-vs-not.html

Comment: @Chrismas007 Yes....the fact that *CalculateFull* seems to fix the problem is a clue that the *UDFs* are not "sufficiently" Volatile on their own. It's difficult to fully answer without seeing the *UDF* code.

Comment: I wonder if the `Private Sub Activate` is in each Sheet's code?

Comment: @Chrismas007: When I hover over the ##### a tooltip displays #VALUE!. I'll adapt my post, thank you for the pointer

Comment: @Gary's Student: I added `Application.Volatile` to all 5 UDF's, but this poses performance issues as all UDF's in the sheet recalculate EVERY time someone enters a number. For 31 days times 3 UDF's per day this takes between 1 and 3 seconds which will be annoying people. In any case, the UDF's on sheet 1 will only need to update when their argument is changed (since I reference to the entire column in the argument of the UDF). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Making the 2 UDF's in sheet 2 volatile seems like a good idea, but it doesn't solve my problem. I still get error 2015, because sheet 1 still needs to `CalculateFull `on the Worksheet_activate event. When I commetn out that event and switch back and forth between tabs, all UDF-containing cells go back to #VALUE! until I hit CTRL+ALT+F9.

Comment: Found this on [ozgrid.com](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA1/excelvba1lesson21.htm)  `To make matters even worse, when you use a line of code in a UDF that cannot be executed you don't receive any error, other than one of the error values (eg; #VALUE!) in the cell housing the UDF. This can make de-bugging UDF's very difficult and leave one scratching their head!` You don't say...

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!

"ActiveSheet" inside a UDF doesn't mean "The Sheet the UDF-containing cell is on" It literally means "the sheet that's active".

When referencing a UDF on anoter sheet, things go horribly wrong. It was all a matter of replacing ActiveSheet with a variable that's set in an If statement that decides from where the UDF is called.
In my case the second sheet always has the word "Info" in it. When on that sheet, you should go one sheet to the left:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

If InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, "Info") = 0 Then
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
Else
    Set ws = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1)
End If
```

Not a 100% waterproof solution (e.g. what if someone reorders the sheets), but for my purposes it's close enough.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet (used within a UDF) should do what you want:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

If TypeOf Application.Caller Is Range Then
    Set ws = Application.Caller.Parent
End If
```

The `Caller` property of the `Application` object points to the `Range` covering the cell(s) where the UDF was called from. `ws` will point to the containing worksheet then.
The `If TypeOf` clause avoids errors in case the function has been called by something else than a UDF (for instance, another VBA procedure), where `Caller` might not point to a `Range` object. In such a case, `ws` remains unassigned (`Nothing`).